# Wrong array values after writing outside the array then using realloc

Tags: c

The output of the first loop is 1..20.
The output of the second loop is 1..30.
And then the third loop goes fine from 1..9 then it outputs 81 at the tenth value for some reason.

Weird thing is if I reallocate 11 elements for the third loop and prints 11 values it prints 1..11 just fine.

What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int *P;
    P = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
        (*(P + (i+1))) = (i+1);
        printf("(%d) Pointer address: %x | Pointer value %d \n", (i+1), (P + (i+1)), *(P + (i+1)));
    };

    P = realloc(P, 30 * sizeof(int));
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------ \n");
    printf("After reallocation... \n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------ \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i ++) {
        if (i > 19)
            (*(P + (i+1))) = (i+1);
        printf("(%d) Pointer address: %x | Pointer value %d \n", (i+1), (P + (i+1)), *(P + (i+1)));
    };


    P = realloc(P, 10 * sizeof(int));
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------ \n");
    printf("After deallocation... \n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------ \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
        printf("(%d) Pointer address: %x | Pointer value %d \n", (i+1), (P + (i+1)), *(P + (i+1)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not at 1... remove all the `+1` from array acesses.

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing `*(P + (i+1))` instead of the simpler `P[i+1]`?

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't feel right.

Comment: It's the normal way. get used to it. When you have a pointer to an array, treat it like an array.

Comment: `P[i+1]` feels *much* more correct than `*(P + (i+1))`.  The latter is extremely unnatural.  Using it communicates a certain level of sophistication which is not complimentary to the author.

Comment: @WilliamPursell

For instance when declaring an static matrix and passing it to a function. Indexing can bite you in the behind.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintStaticMatrix(int pHsize, int pVsize, int *pMatrix) {

  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < pHsize; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < pVsize; j++) 
      j != (pVsize - 1) ? 
      printf("%d ", *((pMatrix + i *pVsize) +j )) : 
      printf("%d \n", *((pMatrix + i *pVsize) +j ));

}
```

If you try to index it it gives you an error.

Comment: @claaudio that is not related at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array indexes start at 0, not at 1. So the last element of the array can be accessed with `*(P + 19)`. When `i = 19` in your first loop, the `(*(P + (i+1))) = (i+1);` writes to `*(P + 20)` which is out of bounds. Accessing memory out of bounds is undefined behavior.

Remove all the `+1` from array accesses in your code to make it behave properly, ie. change all `P + (i+1)` to just `P + i`. Also most programmers very much prefer `P[i]` instead of `*(P + i)` for readability. Also some programmers prefer writing `&P[i]` in place of `P + i` - the address of the `i`th element.

Additionally printing a pointer value with `%x` is undefined behavior. `%x` in `printf` needs its argument to be `unsigned int`. Passing `unsigned int*` value to it is undefined behavior, which just *happens* to work on your machine because most probably size of `unsigned int` is the same as size of `unsigned int *`. The common way to print pointer values is using `%p` `printf` specifier and casting the pointer to `void*`. (Note that on most architectures casting to `void*` is not really needed, as all pointers have the same size, but not doing it is technically undefined behavior.) If you want to still use `%x`, you should rather cast the argument to proper type, like `(unsigned)(uintptr_t)(P + i)`.

Also, you didn't include `#include <stdlib.h>` for `malloc` and `realloc` functions. You should at least see a warning from the compiler about implicit declarations. This is also undefined behavior, because the implicitly declared functions don't match real definitions. The implicit declarations return an `int`, while `malloc` and `realloc` return a `void*`.

Remember about error handling. Each `realloc` and `malloc` can return a `NULL` in case it can't allocate memory.

After fixing those mistakes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int *P;
    P = malloc(20 * sizeof(unsigned int));

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        P[i] = i + 1;
        printf("(%d) Pointer address: %p | Pointer value %d \n", 
            i + 1, (void*)(P + i), P[i]);
    };

    P = realloc(P, 30 * sizeof(unsigned int));
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------ \n");
    printf("After reallocation... \n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------ \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i ++) {
        if (i > 19) {
            P[i] = i + 1;
        }
        printf("(%d) Pointer address: %p | Pointer value %d \n", 
            i + 1, (void*)(P + i), P[i]);
    };


    P = realloc(P, 10 * sizeof(unsigned int));
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------ \n");
    printf("After deallocation... \n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------ \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
        printf("(%d) Pointer address: %p | Pointer value %d \n", 
            i + 1, (void*)(P + i), P[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/pI1Qrv):

```
(1) Pointer address: 0x13c4260 | Pointer value 1 
(2) Pointer address: 0x13c4264 | Pointer value 2 
(3) Pointer address: 0x13c4268 | Pointer value 3 
(4) Pointer address: 0x13c426c | Pointer value 4 
(5) Pointer address: 0x13c4270 | Pointer value 5 
(6) Pointer address: 0x13c4274 | Pointer value 6 
(7) Pointer address: 0x13c4278 | Pointer value 7 
(8) Pointer address: 0x13c427c | Pointer value 8 
(9) Pointer address: 0x13c4280 | Pointer value 9 
(10) Pointer address: 0x13c4284 | Pointer value 10 
(11) Pointer address: 0x13c4288 | Pointer value 11 
(12) Pointer address: 0x13c428c | Pointer value 12 
(13) Pointer address: 0x13c4290 | Pointer value 13 
(14) Pointer address: 0x13c4294 | Pointer value 14 
(15) Pointer address: 0x13c4298 | Pointer value 15 
(16) Pointer address: 0x13c429c | Pointer value 16 
(17) Pointer address: 0x13c42a0 | Pointer value 17 
(18) Pointer address: 0x13c42a4 | Pointer value 18 
(19) Pointer address: 0x13c42a8 | Pointer value 19 
(20) Pointer address: 0x13c42ac | Pointer value 20 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
After reallocation... 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
(1) Pointer address: 0x13c52d0 | Pointer value 1 
(2) Pointer address: 0x13c52d4 | Pointer value 2 
(3) Pointer address: 0x13c52d8 | Pointer value 3 
(4) Pointer address: 0x13c52dc | Pointer value 4 
(5) Pointer address: 0x13c52e0 | Pointer value 5 
(6) Pointer address: 0x13c52e4 | Pointer value 6 
(7) Pointer address: 0x13c52e8 | Pointer value 7 
(8) Pointer address: 0x13c52ec | Pointer value 8 
(9) Pointer address: 0x13c52f0 | Pointer value 9 
(10) Pointer address: 0x13c52f4 | Pointer value 10 
(11) Pointer address: 0x13c52f8 | Pointer value 11 
(12) Pointer address: 0x13c52fc | Pointer value 12 
(13) Pointer address: 0x13c5300 | Pointer value 13 
(14) Pointer address: 0x13c5304 | Pointer value 14 
(15) Pointer address: 0x13c5308 | Pointer value 15 
(16) Pointer address: 0x13c530c | Pointer value 16 
(17) Pointer address: 0x13c5310 | Pointer value 17 
(18) Pointer address: 0x13c5314 | Pointer value 18 
(19) Pointer address: 0x13c5318 | Pointer value 19 
(20) Pointer address: 0x13c531c | Pointer value 20 
(21) Pointer address: 0x13c5320 | Pointer value 21 
(22) Pointer address: 0x13c5324 | Pointer value 22 
(23) Pointer address: 0x13c5328 | Pointer value 23 
(24) Pointer address: 0x13c532c | Pointer value 24 
(25) Pointer address: 0x13c5330 | Pointer value 25 
(26) Pointer address: 0x13c5334 | Pointer value 26 
(27) Pointer address: 0x13c5338 | Pointer value 27 
(28) Pointer address: 0x13c533c | Pointer value 28 
(29) Pointer address: 0x13c5340 | Pointer value 29 
(30) Pointer address: 0x13c5344 | Pointer value 30 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
After deallocation... 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
(1) Pointer address: 0x13c52d0 | Pointer value 1 
(2) Pointer address: 0x13c52d4 | Pointer value 2 
(3) Pointer address: 0x13c52d8 | Pointer value 3 
(4) Pointer address: 0x13c52dc | Pointer value 4 
(5) Pointer address: 0x13c52e0 | Pointer value 5 
(6) Pointer address: 0x13c52e4 | Pointer value 6 
(7) Pointer address: 0x13c52e8 | Pointer value 7 
(8) Pointer address: 0x13c52ec | Pointer value 8 
(9) Pointer address: 0x13c52f0 | Pointer value 9 
(10) Pointer address: 0x13c52f4 | Pointer value 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your malloc/reallocs are too small, so the last value you access in the loop is free for other usage by the compiler, so the behavior when you get to the end of the loop is undefined, whatever you write there may (or may not) get overwritten before you print it. You need to add +1 to each one as you are using *(P+(i+1)), when i ranges from 0..9, you need to access *(P + (9+1)) which requires to allocate  P + 0, to P+10 which requires 11 ints.

For example the last realloc should change from:

`P = realloc(P, 10 * sizeof(int));`

to

`P = realloc(P, (10+1) * sizeof(int));`

Better yet if you don't have all the +1 as the commenters on the question pointed out, and adjust all other code accordingly to what you want, you will have cleaner code.